# How can I force a cognito token refresh from the client

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am using aws amplify and I know that the tokens get automatically refreshed when needed and that that is done behind the scenes.

What I need to do is change a custom attribute on the user in the cognito user pool via a Lambda backend process.  This I can do, and it is working. However, the web client user never sees this new custom attribute and I am thinking the only way they can see it is if the token gets refreshed since the value is stored within the JWT token.

Comment: won't `currentCredentials` https://aws.github.io/aws-amplify/api//classes/auth_auth_.authclass.html#currentcredentials return up to date tokens for you?

Answer (score 12):

The correct solution as of 2021 is to call:

```
await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({bypassCache: true})
```

Comment: This is the answer!

Comment: 2023 and still rolling, unfortunately..

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can update tokens on demand (forcefully)

```js
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

try {
  const cognitoUser = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
  const currentSession = await Auth.currentSession();
  cognitoUser.refreshSession(currentSession.refreshToken, (err, session) => {
    console.log('session', err, session);
    const { idToken, refreshToken, accessToken } = session;
    // do whatever you want to do now :)
  });
} catch (e) {
  console.log('Unable to refresh Token', e);
}
```

Comment: But this can only be done from the frontend, not the server

Answer (score 0):

Like it's said here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html

The access token and ID token are good for 1 hour. With Amplify you can get the info about the session using `currentSession` or `currentUserInfo` in `Auth` class to be able to retrieve information about tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Undocumented, but you can use the `refreshSession` method on the User. Your next call to currentAuthenticatedUser and currentSession will have updated profile attributes (and groups)

```
User = Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
Session =  Auth.currentSession()

User.refreshSession(Session.refreshToken)
```

Comment: Do you know which version of Amplify has this? In the version I'm using I get `User.refreshSession is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

@andreialecu wrote the correct answer. For full code to get the JWT:

```
static async amplifyRefresh() {
    try {
      const currentUser = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({ bypassCache: true })      
      const currentSession = await Auth.currentSession()      
      const jwt = currentSession.getIdToken().getJwtToken()
      // do what you want
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error refreshing token: ", error)
      throw error
    }
  }
```