# How to force auth token refresh with AWS Amplify Android?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-sdk-android

I cannot find information on how to refresh access tokens using AWS' Amplify Android library.

In the documentation, and on some forums, it was suggested that it all happens automatically. But in my case, it does not.

In the app I use Amplify Auth for user authentication, also Amplify Storage and Amplify Predictions.

To query my database, I use the `DynamoDBMapper` from the AWS SDK for Android.

So far I have tried to force refresh the tokens in the following ways:

1. `auth.currentUser`
2. `AWSMovileClient.getInstance().tokens`
3. `AWSMobileClient.getInstance().currentUserState()`
4. `Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession()`

None of the first three were working. `fetchAuthSession(...)` is the technique I am using for now, but it is asynchronous and takes a moment to produce a result. I have to run it synchronously in my `splash activity`. Otherwise, if it is async and there is a request to the database right that depends on its results, the database call will cause a `NotAuthorizedException`.

Also, the refresh token can be set to like 10 years, so it is not a problem at the moment. The problem is that the new access token is not being created after the old one expires, and I cannot do any authenticated user action.

Is there a way to quickly check if tokens are valid -- and if not, refresh them?

Comment: Does the following response solve your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55614839/1721793

Comment: @kekec: this was @baltekg’s question. That link points to some JavaScript code.

Comment: You are right. Here is a github issue asking for a similar functionality, and in this response they point how to achieve this in Android: https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/issues/1204#issuecomment-569900713

Comment: @kekec i have already seen this issue and this technique doesn't work, getTokens() returns previous tokens and does not refresh them. Maybe sometimes it does, but from my testing, it was failing to do so.

Comment: If you force a session refresh and ask for tokens?

Comment: If i do what someone suggested in the answer in the link you provided

Comment: ok, so that solved the issue? There was a follow-up issue addressing this same problem here: https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/issues/2084

Comment: no, it doesn't work. It returns tokens but does not refresh them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224848/discussion-between-kekec-and-baltekg).

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at the source code of "fetchauthsession", and changed the asynchronous mode to synchronous mode.

https://github.com/shichonghuotian/Amplify-token-sync